# Setting up Nginx to *not* retry on Rails timeouts

Tags: nginx, timeout

I have a Rails+Phusion Passenger set-up. Sometimes, the user query that Nginx is proxying to Passenger/Rails times out. How can we set Nginx such that after keepalive_timeout, Nginx does *NOT* retry but rather just reports the error - likely a 502 - and just keep going on rather than re-trying the 'bad' controller/action again and again

Answer (score 4):

```
  proxy_read_timeout 600;
      proxy_next_upstream off;
```

Increase the timeout and turn off the upstream retry
http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_next_upstream

The stops the resubmit after 60 seconds but we still find a resubmit after 305 seconds.  Don't know why, so we have done this:
      proxy_read_timeout 600;

To timeout after 5 min and user gets a 504